# Show a part of a text according to user

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a form that has 3 types of options:

```
    <form action="main.php?page=values" method="post">
    <select name=values>
    <option value="A">1</option>
    <option value="B">2</option>
    <option value="C">3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

In the page "values", there is the insert into a MySql db, and every option has a sample text.

```
if (query('get',$_POST['values'])=='A') {
$text = "Text A (Sub-text A)";
} elseif (query('get',$_POST['values'])=='B') {
$text = "Text B (Sub-text B)";
} elseif (query('get',$_POST['values'])=='C') {
$text = "Text C (Sub-text C)";
} 

query_ok("INSERT INTO chat (id, user, text) VALUES ('$id', '$login', '$text')");
```

When I have to select and show this insert, I would like to show this text in 2 different ways:

a) If user = $login -> Text A/B/C (Sub-text A/B/C)
b) If user != $login -> Text A/B/C

What can I do in order to have this result.

This is the select part:

```
$show= query_ok("SELECT chat.*, user.*
FROM chat
LEFT JOIN user ON user.name = chat.user
WHERE chat.id = ".$_SESSION['id_chat']." 
ORDER BY id", 'result');

while ($row = query_ok($show, 'fetch'))
{
//results
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use array, ex :

```
if (query('get',$_POST['values'])=='A') {
    $text = [
        'user' => 'Text A (Sub-text A)',
        'not_user' => 'Text A'
    ];
} elseif (query('get',$_POST['values'])=='B') {
    $text = [
        'user' => 'Text B (Sub-text B)',
        'not_user' => 'Text B'
    ];
} elseif (query('get',$_POST['values'])=='C') {
    $text = [
        'user' => 'Text C (Sub-text C)',
        'not_user' => 'Text C'
    ];
}
```

AND

a) If user = $login -> $text['user]

b) If user != $login -> $text['not_user]

Comment: Thanks for your comment! There's only one thing I cannot understand in this array: if I chose this solution, it would insert the result according to the user who submit the form? 'cause the form can only be used by $login and $text changes accoring to user who reads the text (Login will read the full text, others only the first part of it)